# In Rails, how do I write a validation rule to validate that both fields should be present or neither be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.  I have a model with a couple of fields

```
first_name
last_name
```

How do I write a validation rule to specify that if one is present, then the other one must be as well?  It is fine if they are both blank but basically they must either be present or neither be present.  How do I write a rule for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options here. You can either use a conditional validation or write a custom validation to do this check.

With a conditional validation:

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, if: -> {last_name.present?}
```

With a custom validation:

```
validate :both_or_neither_present
# ...
def both_or_neither_present
  # if only one of the fields is present
  if (first_name.present? ^ last_name.present?)
    errors.add(:name, "Only part of the name was given")
  end
end
```

With the second one you can write a custom error message. With the first, the error will always be on the :first_name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Glyoko's post:

```
validates :first_name, presence: { 'Last name is missing' }, if: -> {last_name.present?}
validates :last_name, presence: { 'First name is missing' }, if: -> {first_name.present?}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be usefull

```
validates_presence_of :last_name, :if => :first_name? (or vice versa)
```

then you need to make a first_name method that returns a boolean, something like:

```
def first_name?
  first_name.present?
  #If the user have a first_name Validates that the specified attributes is not blank
end
```

Check [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of) for reference.